# preview email development in PHP

Tags: php, email, testing

Once or twice a year i find myself in the position of having to develop complex emails.
They often include Plaintext and Html versions, along with attachments and other headers.

Previewing the development using standard send/receive is painfully slow and tedious.

What i'm looking for is a local testing platform that processes the mail function and provides a mail client style preview with access to alternate views, headers, etc.  Or possibly a real mail client that can take mail directly.

I've searched and searched but no luck so far, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance. TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now solved this.

In the php.ini file there is an option to set an export path for the mail function called `sendmail_path`.

I set this to `tee mail.eml > /dev/null` and it now saves the sent mail to the same directory as where the function is called and i simply open it with my mail client.

> sendmail_path = tee mail.eml > /dev/null

2 notes on this.

1. this is a solution for unix platforms only.
2. the file extension has to be set to suit your chosen mail client

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can use your localhost mail and access it via thunderbird for example

[How do I read local email in thunderbird? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-read-local-email-in-thunderbird)

Via this way you don't have to wait endless for mail to be delivered as it's local. And you can see your send mail in a actual mail client

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any software but I had some good experience with the following online service: http://litmus.com/ It's somewhat like browserstack. (live crossbrowser testing tool)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/), which listens to a SMTP port, catchs all e-mails and shows headers, source, text and html view. It's very useful!

Comment: ... but it's windows-only as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

For a task like this I use [fakemail](http://www.lastcraft.com/fakemail.php) for receiving the mails into a maildir and [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) for reading the mails. Mutt can also be configured for reading HTML mails.

If you just want to log the emails without reading them, you could use the "logmail" approach described in [this article by Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/dec/php-advent-calendar-day-1):

Edit: The lastcraft.com host seems to be down at the moment, my Google search for "fakemail" revealed this Python project that might be helpful: https://github.com/isotoma/FakeEmail

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to preview your HTML emails (and alternatively, if you need help designing them) you can sign up for a free [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) account. It's actually an email send service, but they also have an interface for a drag-and-drop email builder.

For your situation, you could use the "code your own" tool, drop in your HTML, CSS, plain text, etc. and then preview the email in all sorts of email clients, test at different screen resolutions, etc.

(*I am not affiliated with MailChimp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try https://github.com/ycecube/phpmaildebug.

It uses the php's sendmail output to capture the mails.